# Calling a method from a different .cpp file

Tags: qt, methods

I want to save some data as a text file, the first txt file will contain header information, the other text file will save data streamed from sensors, so with the help from the internet I created the following "datalogger.cpp" file

```
#include "datalogger.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QFile>

DataLogger::DataLogger(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

   DataLogger::~DataLogger(){

}
void DataLogger::save(DataStream &input){
    saveAsText(input);


}
void DataLogger::saveAsText(DataStream &input){

                    QTextStream outHeader(&outFileHeader);

                    outHeader   << "[CAPTURE SETTINGS]\n"
                                << "Filename: " <<      SettingsSingleton::instance().getFileName() << ".txt \n"
                                << "Samples: " <<       QString::number(input.size()) << "\n"
                                << "Duration: " <<      QString::number(input.back().time) << "ms \n"
                                << "Sample rate: " <<   QString::number(SettingsSingleton::instance().getSampleRate()) << " Hz\n"
                                << "Source: "  <<       SettingsSingleton::instance().getSource() << "\n"                                  

                    outFileHeader.close();

                }

                QFile outFile(SettingsSingleton::instance().getFileName() + ".txt");

                 QTextStream out(&outFile);                      

                    for (int i ; i<input.size();i++){
                           const EcgStreamObject tmp=input.at(i);
                                            out << tmp.toText() << endl; //"\n";    

                    }  

                    outFile.close();
                }    

}
```

I have my "DataStream" input variable that I want to pass to the method and save as a ".txt" file, however I do no know how to call the method "void DataLogger::save(DataStream &input)" from a different ".cpp" file where the DataStream variable is located. 
I am extremely new to c++ please it as simple as possible please.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You could display the complete code of the other file.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, it is about how to create and use a header file in c++.

There is already a lot of information about this, for example [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) article from cplusplus.com or [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/) from learncpp.com.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add "datalogger.h" to your other file.

When you call the method DataLogger::save from your other file, the program will search for an implementation that was linked to your program (i.e. the file you posted here) and use that to actually perform the work.

Stefan's answer is probably important to look at too as it will cover this case and some other basics if you are going to be working in C/C++ long term.

Comment: I would also be careful using Qt for simple things like writing files and string formatting. It's nice sometimes, but you have to include Qt library files with your program for it to run properly and compiling/linking/running Qt can get a little hairy in my past experiences when not doing a full Qt GUI. There are very easy ways to accomplish the same result with pure C/C++. Again see Stefan's links.